# JOIN Statement For Multiple Tables Not Working

Tags: mysql

I just started learning SQL last night.  I'm having trouble displaying data using multiple JOIN statements.  The tables I have are:

```
Table: CUSTOMER
Contains CustomerID, Country, Last Name

Table: TRANS
Contains CustomerID, TransactionID, DateSold, WorkID

Table: WORK
Contains WorkID, Title, Description
```

Here's my query:

```
Select CUSTOMER.LastName, CUSTOMER.CustomerID, WORK.WorkID, 
        Description, Title

FROM CUSTOMER JOIN TRANS
        ON CUSTOMER.CustomerID = TRANS.CustomerID

JOIN WORK
        ON TRANS.WorkID = WORK.WorkID

WHERE DateSold = '11/17/2014'

GROUP BY CUSTOMER.CustomerID, TRANS.CustomerID, CUSTOMER.LastName,
         WORK.WorkID, Title, DateSold, Description
```

Note that in the select statement, I've deliberately left out a few items that appear in the GROUP BY statement, just for the sake of this post.  (Their inclusion in the SELECT statement doesn't cause program to execute properly.)

All that appears is the GROUP BY statement, but no actual data.  Please help me with what I'm doing wrong.  Thank you.

Comment: What data-type is `DateSold`?  If it's a native DATE based data-type, your date string should follow ***international standards*** and be `'2014-11-17'` *(unless you've changed your MySQL server's settings)*

Comment: Please include the error message you get when you try to execute that query. Also, SQL and MySQL have some differences, so could you please tell us exactly which one you are currently using?

Comment: Please define "not working": Are you getting an error, or not getting the results you're expecting? Also, a couple of suggestions not necessarily related: (1). When joining tables together, all your columns (e.g. in the `SELECT` clause) should have an alias; (2) Always specify what type of join you're doing (`LEFT` or `INNER` at least).

Comment: I think it would be VERY helpful to add some sample data and your desired results so we can understand what you are trying to do without having to reverse engineer your SQL and guess.

Comment: switch the first join to be trans join customers

Comment: try removing your where clause and see if any data is returned.  Your syntax is correct, most likely you don't have any records returned in your result set

Comment: A group by without aggregate functions is fairly pointless.

Comment: @mdo123, I initially didn't have a WHERE clause and too much data was returned for my liking.  However, that was before I made some modifications.  I tried your method and I'm getting better results, but I'd still like to filter by date.

Comment: @Nikki removing the where clause will return all records that join on your conditions.  As your first comment noted you're date format is not correct, unless you made it that way on purpose, which wouldn't make any sense.  Try looking at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp.  More than likely you just need to change your where clause to.. WHERE DateSold = '2014-11-07' .... OR WHERE DateSold >= '2014-11-07'

Comment: I deleted old comments.  It turns out I was simply entering the wrong data.  Wow!  The date format I have actually works fine.  I appreciate the time you all spent helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `STR_TO_DATE` function in mysql to convert the date string.

```
WHERE DateSole = STR_TO_DATE('11/17/2014', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join one table with two different table but you have to start from the common table.
For how you wrote the query you are saying to join CUSTOMER first with TRANS and then with WORK but the conditions are wrong for this situation (and it is not what you want to do).

```
Select CUSTOMER.LastName, CUSTOMER.CustomerID, WORK.WorkID, 
        Description, Title

FROM TRANS JOIN CUSTOMER
        ON CUSTOMER.CustomerID = TRANS.CustomerID

JOIN WORK
        ON TRANS.WorkID = WORK.WorkID

WHERE DateSold = '11/17/2014'

GROUP BY CUSTOMER.CustomerID, TRANS.CustomerID, CUSTOMER.LastName,
         WORK.WorkID, Title, DateSold, Description
```

It is TRANS that you join first with CUSTOMER and then with WORK.

Comment: I fixed the issue I was having.  Thanks for your explanation, I didn't know that.